# How to simplify a complex many to many relationship where one key does not directly map to an id?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

It was quite hard to come up with a title for my problem so please forgive me.

When the project started, there used to be a simple many to many relationship. Eloquent made this a breeze. There are coverflows and contentpackages, basically the same as categories and posts.

```
public function contentpackages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('WebCreator\Contentpackages\Contentpackage')
        ->withPivot('name', 'cover', 'released_at', 'order')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->orderBy('pivot_order', 'asc');
}
```

A new feature that was requested are revisions for the contentpackages. The way I realized that feature is to add two columns to the contentpackage table: `parent_id, current`

parent_id holds the id of the root contentpackage. Every update to that contentpackage will create a new row with parent_id = id of the first row of that contentpackage.

current is a flag that is set to 1 for the chosen (current) revision.

That makes selecting all current revisions very easy:

```
return $this
        ->contentpackage
        ->where('current', '=', 1)
        ->get();
```

Okay. So far so good, now I need to update the relationship to represent that behavior. At the moment, it would select the first revision of each contentpackage, not the current one. A solution I was thinking about is to update the pivot table every time that I update a contentpackage, to link to the new id. However that does not feel right to me and has some pitfalls. For example if one user updates a coverflow (attaches new contentpackages by posting the IDs to the api) and at about the same time somebody else updates a contentpackage, there will be inconsistencies. So the contentpackage_id in the pivot table has to point to the root revision.

I came up with this solution, which works and satisfies the tests, but makes me cringe. There has to be a smoother way to do this, however I am no sql ninja, so I did not come up with one.

```
 public function getContentpackages()
{
    // get pivot
    $pivotrows  = DB::table('contentpackage_coverflow')->where('coverflow_id', '=', $this->id)->orderBy('order')->get();
    $attached   = DB::table('contentpackage_coverflow')->where('coverflow_id', '=', $this->id)->lists('contentpackage_id');

    $contentpackages = Contentpackage::where('current', '=', 1)
        ->where(function($query) use ($attached) {
        $query
            ->whereIn('parent_id', $attached)
            ->orWhereIn('id', $attached);
        })
        ->get();

    $result = new Collection();
    foreach($pivotrows as $row)
    {
        foreach($contentpackages as $package)
        {
            if($row->contentpackage_id == $package->id || $row->contentpackage_id == $package->parent_id)
            {
                $np = $package->replicate(); // replicate, so that it is not a reference
                $np->id = $package->id;      // the id will be unset by replicate
                $np->pivot = $row;           // add pivot data
                $result->push($np);
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;

}
```

So what is happening here? I query the pivot table to get a list of all contentpackages I need to get. Then I query the pivot table again to get the pivot data (there is some additional information).

The next step is to loop through the pivot data and fill a collection with the contentpackages. Note that one contentpackage may be in a coverflow multiple times. So I need to replicate the model in order to attach the pivot data and not overwrite it in one reference. Replicating the model unsets the id, which is good, but not for my use, so I set it again.

Is there a way to clean this up, maybe even use the many to many relationship of laravel but extend it in a way that it satisfies my needs?

Or did I screw up on the way and there is a better way to achieve the revision history. Using a seperate Table for revisions came to my mind, but actually I like the employed way better.

*Please give me your opinions and help me clean up my mess :)*

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Laravel, but I think this is more a question about the design of your database then the usage.

If I get it right you have `coverflows` and `contentpackages` which have a many to many relationship.

Then the came have revisions of the contentpackages. You tried to solve it by adding the `parent_id` and `current` columns to the `contentpackages` table. You got it working but you have a code smell, you think, well I kinda have to agree :P

---

How I would tackle this issue (in your setup);

Introduce a new table `contentpackage_revisions`

It is a very small table

```
id INT(11) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
contentpackage_id FOREIGN KEY to the content package,
occured_on DATETIME NOT NULL, 
data TEXT
```

In the `data` column I would hold a json object of the changes that happend. Now in the `contentpackages` you would always have the latest version, but can use the `contentpackage_revsions` to show what happend.

---

Personally I use [event sourcing](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html), which is a revision system by it self.

Comment: I thought of a similar approach, but I did not want to save data as json objects. However your approach is perfectly good as far as the db design goes. I guess I just wanted to avoid adding another table. Wordpress inspired me to use this approach, as all revisions are saved in the posts table. Given that wp is not the most beautiful piece of software architecture, that approach kind of stuck with me.

Comment: You could make a copy of the db with all the columns etc so you don't need to use the JSON. But well that is copy paste. But then again if you need to use SQL on your revision data you need the columns. You could look into PostgreSQL (JSON support) of a NoSQL db (ie. MongoDB)